# nodejs packet parser structure

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have a packet, when viewed in hex is:

```
0A 00 2C 01 23 00 0C 00 B3 01
```

`0A 00` is the length which is 10.
`2C 01` is a identifier `12c` or could be a decimal packet id.
`23 00` is a version of dec 35.
`0C 00` is another version which is dec 12.
`b3 01` is 435.

Now I am using [packet](http://bigeasy.github.io/node-packet/#packet) for nodejs.

```
http://bigeasy.github.io/node-packet/
```

I currently have this code,

```
parser.extract("b16 => length, b16 => id, b16 => clientVersion, b16 => updateVersion, b16 => dateVersion", function (record) {
  console.log(record);
});
parser.parse(data);
```

These are the issues here, the extract returns

```
length: 2560, version: 11265... etc. ( which is all wrong )
```

Question is what is going wrong?

---

changing everything to `b8` still gives me the correct length which is `10` but everything else is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the [`Endianness`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your values incorrectly. `0A 00` is `10` in little-endian form, but you have specified it as `b16` (the `b` meaning big-endian).

```
parser.extract(
    "l16 => length, " +
    "l16 => id, " +
    "l16 => clientVersion, " +
    "l16 => updateVersion, " +
    "l16 => dateVersion",
    function (record) {
```

Comment: oh, I actually thought it was big endian. My mistake. anyways. Thank you very much,